# What is the asymptotic value of the smoothed probability in a HMM model?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian-network

If I have a HMM model with a hidden markov chain $(S_t)_t$ with 3 states and if I assume that the distribution of the observation knowing in which state it is, is a normal. Do I know what is the value asymptotic of the smoothed probabilities? In other words what is $P(S_t=s|Y_1,..,Y_{\infty})$?